# How do I get all taxonomies a post is related to - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

Thanks for taking the time to look at this question and hopefully you can help!

I'm looking to run a wordpress query which retrieves all taxonomies related to another.

For example; say I have a category/taxonomy of products and a category/taxonomy of sub products in my Wordpress site. When I land on a product category/taxonomy page, I would like to see a list of all the related sub categories/taxonomies.

I hope this makes sense as after many hours spent googling, all I can find are questions asking how to get all posts related to a taxonomy - not the other way round!

Many thanks in advance!

Patrick

Comment: Are sub product categories children of the product categories?

Comment: Hi Bobdye, Thanks for taking the time to look at my problem. So in this example I have a list of products which can be filtered by; manufacturer, condition, type (for example; Tractors, Lawn mowers etc) and sub-type (for example; Junior, Adult, Accessories etc). What I need to do is when a user filters by manufacurer the site then displays the relevant types and sub-types for that manufacturer. I hope this makes sense! Sorry for the long comment.

Comment: I understand generally what you're trying to accomplish. What I was trying to find out was if "sub-type" is just terminology, or whether it indicated a relationship. It sounds from your example like sub-type is really just another category/taxonomy for selecting products, and is not a "child" of any of the other criteria.

Comment: "sub-type" or any other categories/taxonomies aren't parent/child related, no. You're correct with your understanding of my example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you would like to get the taxonomies and terms that apply to the products listed on a particular page, e.g. a category or taxonomy page.

Suppose that you have an array of product IDs $product_id, for example the IDs of products currently being displayed. You should be able to get the taxonomies and terms that apply to those products as follows:

```
global $wpdb;

$ids = implode(',', $product_id);
$query = "SELECT x.taxonomy, t.name FROM wp_term_taxonomy AS x
          JOIN wp_term AS t on t.term_id = x.term_id
          JOIN wp_terms_relationships AS r on r.term_taxonomy_id = x.term_taxonomy_id
          WHERE r.object_id IN ($ids)
          GROUP BY x.taxonomy, t.name";
$taxonomies = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
```

In the above:

```
SELECT x.taxonomy, t.name FROM wp_term_taxonomy AS x
```

is the base table of taxonomies (names) and the term_ids of their terms.

```
JOIN wp_terms AS t on t.term_id = x.term_id
```

matches each of the term_ids from wp_term_taxonomy with its term name.

```
JOIN wp_term_relationships AS r on r.term_taxonomy_id = x.term_taxonomy_id
```

then matches that with entries in wp_term_relationships which shows which products (custom post IDs) use those terms.

```
WHERE r.object_id IN ($ids)
```

limits the list to only those terms relevant for the products in your list.

Since, in this example, we are asking for x.taxonomy and t.name,

```
GROUP BY x.taxonomy, t.name
```

makes sure that you don't have duplicates. You could get additional fields if you needed by changing the SELECT.

So, once you run get_results(), you should have an array of objects, each with a taxonomy name and term name. The general scheme will be:

```
+-----------+-------+
| taxonomy1 | term1 |
+-----------+-------+
| taxonomy1 | term2 |
+-----------+-------+
| taxonomy1 | term1 |
+-----------+-------+
| taxonomy2 | term1 |
+-----------+-------+
| taxonomy3 | term1 |
+-----------+-------+
...
```

You can now use this to create a way for visitors to select a further subset, e.g. by creating a dropdown of terms for each taxonomy.

Comment: Hi bobdye, Thank you for taking the time to submit the above answer. Unfortunately I've only just had a chance to try the code so apologies for the delay in getting back to you! All I get returned by running the code you've provided is a blank array. Could you further investigate why this might be? Your help is much appreciated in advance! :-)

Comment: My apologies bobdye, having run the query directly in phpMyAdmin it notified me of an error in your query - 'wp_term' should be 'wp_terms', easy mistake to make though and it appears to be working now!