# Wordpress: Fastest way to return all post attributes from a category

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, taxonomy

I am trying to build an "attribute filter" system for custom post type in Wordpress. To do this, I need to know for any category the total attributes for all the posts within that category. To achieve this, I create a secondary loop that goes through each and every product in the category, retrieves the terms/taxonomy for each attribute.

The problem is that this is very expensive, especially when some categories will have thousands of posts and each hundreds of different groups of attributes.

Is there any more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: You should be able to do it with a query using JOINs. What are attributes? Taxonomy terms or meta values?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, they are taxonomy terms (posts are actually products here, I'm working with WooCommerce), but I'm just concerned that there are A LOT. I've been using WP_query like I said to re-run the loop for posts and then for each post query the attributes then query the taxonomy information all of which is very resource intensive. If you believe a query will be better than that would be awesome!

Comment: I answered an essentially similar question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811154/how-do-i-get-all-taxonomies-a-post-is-related-to-wordpress/28862079#28862079